# EditText.setText error

Tags: java, android

RESOLVED! The problem is that I used this.findViewById, but I will use dialog.findViewById. TNX TO ALL AND I BEG YOUR PARDON!

I've a strange (for me) problem. I try to write in a edittext with a string readed from a cursor, and i know that's the correct way:

```
EditText myText;

     final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
     dialog.setContentView(R.layout.login);
     dialog.setTitle("Login");
     dialog.setCancelable(true);

     Cursor lista=db.listaParametri();

     try
        {
            while (lista.moveToNext())
            {

                if (lista.getString(0).equals("username"))
                {

                    myText =  (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.username);

                    Log.d("log", lista.getString(1));

                    myText.setText( lista.getString(1) );




                }



            }
        }
        finally
        {
            lista.close();
        }
```

But when try to write whit settext() return this error:

```
06-10 09:43:01.829: E/AndroidRuntime(279): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-10 09:43:01.829: E/AndroidRuntime(279): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-10 09:43:01.829: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at it.axiomatic.epsoft.sms.EpsoftSMSActivity.setup_parametri(EpsoftSMSActivity.java:147)
06-10 09:43:01.829: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at it.axiomatic.epsoft.sms.EpsoftSMSActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(EpsoftSMSActivity.java:73)
06-10 09:43:01.829: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2195)
06-10 09:43:01.829: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:730)
06-10 09:43:01.829: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:143)
06-10 09:43:01.829: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
06-10 09:43:01.829: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:532)
06-10 09:43:01.829: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:122)
06-10 09:43:01.829: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
06-10 09:43:01.829: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-10 09:43:01.829: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-10 09:43:01.829: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-10 09:43:01.829: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-10 09:43:01.829: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 09:43:01.829: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-10 09:43:01.829: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-10 09:43:01.829: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-10 09:43:01.829: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What's up? Tnx!

Comment: You received a NullPointerException, which means that something is not defined and you are accessing its properties or performing methods upon it.  It seems as if lista is null; print lista and see what the result is.

Comment: Look at line number 147 in EpsoftSMSActivity.java and make sure you don't have any NULL variables there.

Comment: After seeing another [recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948678/java-lang-nullpointerexception-error-on-a-query) of yours related to NPEs, I recommend you learn what NullPointerExceptions are, what causes them, and how to avoid them.

Comment: the row 147 is myText.setText( lista.getString(1));

lista is a cursor and is defined pefectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either:

1. Your textedit has not been defined properly (But if you can do other things with itthen it should be fine)
2. `lista.getString(1)` is null, try printing it with catlog by saying `Log.d("log", lista.getString(1));` which should output the value of the string.

Comment: Tried second option and that's ok, the log return correct value.

Comment: Post the code around like 147 of your app.

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED! The problem is that I used this.findViewById, but I will use dialog.findViewById. TNX TO ALL AND I BEG YOUR PARDON!

Comment: Welcome to SO, Axiomatic.it. Please note that SO doesn't work like other forums. This is not a linear forum with posts and replies, so this particular post does not belong here. Down here, it's answers only. Maybe if you reworded the post, removed the SHOUTING and the greetings, it could be considered an answer. And if it is the correct answer, you could even accept your own answer eventually.